# How to declare static nested object

Tags: java, oop

How to declare a nested static object in java and access them.

This is my current working code. I have try to declare the child as static , but that give me an error. **But in the main class I can't get the child. Is there anyway to achieve this?**

```
public class A {

    public static Parent parent= new Parent("abc") {
            public Child child1 = new Child("efg1");
            public Child child2 = new Child("efg2");
    }


    public static Parent parent1= new Parent("abc") {
            public Child child3 = new Child("efg1");
            public Child child4 = new Child("efg2");
    }

}

public class Main{

    public void run() {
        A.parent.child1; //this is not working , the android studio can only access parent.
        A.parent1.child3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the parent class?

Comment: If your `parent` variable is of type `Parent`, then you can only access member variables through it that are declared in the `Parent` class.

Comment: @vinS its a game structure , and I have no problem in accessing 'A.parent' in main.

Comment: The problem is not accessing `A.parent`, it's `parent.child1`; `Parent` does not have that field, only the anonymous subclass you declare for the `static` member.

Comment: is there anyway to achieve this? I want to access static field like this . A.parent.child1

Comment: I am not able to understand `{
        public Child child1 = new Child("efg1");
        public Child child2 = new Child("efg2");
    }` part. Will you please update your code, so that it will be compiled?

Comment: From the way you defined `Parent` it seems like an anonymous class and I don't think you can define it in this manner.

Comment: @Omoro any advice on achieving what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write in a simple way like below :

```
public class Main {

    public void run() {
        Child child = A.parent.child1;
    }
}

class A {
    public static Parent parent = new Parent("abc");
}

class Parent {

    public Parent(String s) {
        // Do whatever with string s
    }

    public Child child1 = new Child("efg1");
    public Child child2 = new Child("efg2");
}

class Child {

    public Child(String s) {
        // Do whatever with string s
    }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple intance of parent , parent1 , parent2 , with different child1,child2,child3,child4. this is why I din't design it this way

Comment: Until unless you will not provide a compiled code with all class declaration (minimal), we will not be able to understand your requirement. Here you can have  
`class A {
     public static Parent parent1 = new Parent("abc"); public static Parent parent2 = new Parent("abc");
}` as many instances of Parent, you required.

Comment: child is not fixed. it can be any count. sometimes can be more than 20

Comment: As far as I have understood, I would maintain a Collection of Child in parent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Parent` is nested in `A` and `Child` in `Parent` and both `Parent` and `Child` are nested static classes, you can do this:

```
public class A{
    public static class Parent {
       public Parent(String parentStr) {}

       public static class Child{
           public Child(String childStr) {}
       }
    }
}

public class Main{

    public void run() {
       A.Parent parent = new A.Parent("parent");
       A.Parent.Child child = new A.Parent.Child("child");
   }
}
```